# Can open file only through Windows Photo's

Tags: image, server, jpeg

I have an .jpg of 503Mb and 61920x25920 pixels. I can only open the file in Windows Photo's. If I upload it to my local server I can't seem to open it. In Chrome it's a small cube, even if I open the file locally. When I copy the image on a flash drive and open it on another pc it works fine (through Windows Photo's).

Link to image:
https://timwens.ink/media/images/Hogwarts%20Legacy%20Super-Resolution%202023.03.15%20-%2013.47.54.29.jpg

wget info:

```
PS C:\Users\twens> wget https://timwens.ink/media/images/Hogwarts%20Legacy%20Super-Resolution%202023.03.15%20-%2013.47.54.29.jpg


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {255, 216, 255, 224...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    CF-Cache-Status: HIT
                    Server-Timing: cf-q-config;dur=7.0000023697503e-06
                    Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=ZEEWvJG...
Headers           : {[Connection, keep-alive], [CF-Cache-Status, HIT], [Server-Timing, cf-q-config;dur=7.0000023697503e
                    -06], [Report-To, {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=ZEEWvJGc01pOi9
                    Y%2BdJL%2BPagP1Oyqho2XKTpKHwjrwW2e70nL%2BRg6Z0rd5l6Ns5Rdk2C5zHMbLLIWIJSlyUZCg1zP%2FQ12rZzEjktCZJk2U
                    dEAEyy2RI1PfSuXX%2F9REA%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}]...}
RawContentLength  : 528095309
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Gwenview can open that file, also GIMP can do that, and also [my decoder](https://github.com/xbarin02/jpeg) can do that.

Comment: Alright I see, but how do I make it accessible through the link for anyone?

Comment: I would try some JavaScript JPEG decoder ([the first link in Google](https://hhelwich.github.io/jp3g/)).